# Sitecore Multisite Best Practice for setting up Visual Studio Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, multisite, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I'm seeking an advise on best practice that has worked for creating a asp.net MVC visual studio solution that supports multisite (multi tenant). One thing we would like to do is minimize the regression defects so that developer don't modify the wrong website code base etc.

in my mind there are 2 approaches.

Approach 1:

```
-Services (Project)
    |- Site A
        |-Service.cs
    |- Site B
        |-Serviceb.cs
|-Repository(Project)
    |- Site A
        |- Repository.cs
    |- Site B
        |- Repositorya.cs
|-MVC (Project)
    |-Areas
        |-Site A
            |- Controller
            |- View
        |-Site B
            |- Controller
            |- View
    |-Content
        |-Site A
            |- CSS
            |- JS
        |-Site A
            |- CSS
            |- JS
```

Approach 2

```
-Services.SiteA (Project)
        |-Service.cs
-Services.SiteB (Project)
        |-Serviceb.cs
-Repository.SiteA(Project)
        |- Repository.cs
-Repository.Site B(Project)
        |- Repositorya.cs
-MVC.SiteA (Project)
        |- Controller
        |- View
        |Content
            |- CSS
            |- JS

-MVC.Site B
        |- Controller
        |- View
        |Content
            |- CSS
            |- JS
```

Could someone please help me with which option may be better? Not that the solution needs to support more than 8 web sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have got one more alternative to address that. Currently working on a huge project, with dozens of developers and quite bureaucratic process of deployments, we have introduced the following approach:

1. Project consists of multiple logical subparts, which in fact are individual websites.
2. Each of those websites we set up as an MVC Area with own controllers, views etc
3. **Most important** - we set up MVC Areas as individually pluggable DLLs. So each of that websites is a separate project under solution, with its own resources and statics; on build everything is copied under their required paths and DLL goes to the \bin folder.
4. One more class library for shared (by all websites) resources, it is being referenced only by those sites, that need that functionality
5. In Sitecore, we have the same strict principles - the content, layouts, renderings are isolated as higher as possible, no individual content may be re-used (unless from shared resources folder).

This approach serves us almost a year already and has proven for its agility, much **easier deployment** and fairly **less code merge conflicts**. If you are working under just one site - you don't need to re-compile and re-deploy everything - just replace one dll at bin folder.

Thus, combining that with your question, **Approach 1** would be an answer.

References (more to read):

[Sitecore MVC areas as pluggable separate DLL - making areas further more independent](http://blog.martinmiles.net/post/sitecore-mvc-areas-as-a-separate-dll-making-areas-further-more-independent)

[Sitecore with MVC Areas as pluggable Module](http://cprakash.com/2014/10/27/sitecore-and-mvc-areas-as-pluggable-module/)

Comment: Thanks @Marin, how about having Solution for each website and have master solution that contains all solution. That way each team/vendor can work on their own solution. This may require strict naming conventions etc.

Comment: Yes, that would work with multiple solutions as well (I am having tow of them at he moment, but can be any number). The only concern is to make sure Area's bin compiled libraries are copied on build to the correct directory (bin of master website). Alternatively you may have use from Solution Folders within one solution - either would work for you

Comment: Hi Martin. For multiple solution option, what's the best way to manage the web.configuration file in solution (given that each site may require their own web.config file for adding nuget package dll references etc.)

Comment: Very good question!!! What I do - for each website's area (in project) create  it's own App_Config/Include folder and create <project_name>.config file there and keep all site-specific settings there.  On build that file is getting copied into main <web_root>\App_config\Include folder along with the rest of include patch config files.

Answer (score 3):

My personal preference is to keep everybody together in the same website project as it forces the teams to think about their impact on each other, but also to look for potential savings through re-use.

In your structure, you should also consider the concept of 'shared' views and controllers that all sites would be able to use. There are some simple views (like error message renderings) that often just need to have a different CSS applied to them to keep them on brand. Make sure your structure supports this type of re-use.

So, of the two options you presented, my preference would be for Approach 1 with some small adjustments to support shared JS, CSS, views, and controllers.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I also preferred the same as you mentioned until we have complete separate requirement for new multi-site